# Angular2 list of anchor object to template

Tags: angular

to simplify let's say my component from a service get a list of anchor something like:

```
Url:{href:h1, text:t1} etc
```

in my template I have a table and like to show text of Url.

```
<tr *ngFor="let r of rs">
<td><span>{{r.Url.text}}</span></td>
```

it will show `[Object Object]` I tried also `r[Url][text]` and all other combinations for no avail how can I get the value in my template.

Sorry for confusion. The list is an array of object like 
`obj = {f1:string, f2:url}` with

```
url ={text:string, href:string}
```

Comment: How are you retrieving those items from the service? Show us the code.

Comment: the list is ok. there are more fields and they show correctly in the table.

Comment: You'd have to share some code. From what we are currently seing, there is nothing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for asking the wrong question. Actually the problem was a mistake in *ngSwitchCase. I was doing `<a *ngSwitchCase="station" href="{{radio.station.href}}">` and It never get this case and was getting the *ngSwitchDefault. By changing `*ngSwitchCase="'station'"` everything is working correctly. Thank you again for your help and I posted this answer for others with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided

In your component, you have something like (list of URLs)

```
public urls: Url[] = [{href:h1, text:t1}, {href:h2, text:t2}]; //get this from service
```

Then in your view, following should work

```
<tr *ngFor="let url of urls">
   <td><span>{{url.text}}</span></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Unfortunately my list is not that simple is more like:
list = {f1,f2,f3={href,text}, etc}. 
How can I get f3.href or f3.text

Comment: This doesn't look like any valid information, can you edit your question to include a little code that shows what your list holds after your service call.

Comment: @FrenchiInLA That looks more like an object, then you cannot iterate it with ngFor, ngFor only works with arrays.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. The list is an array of object like 
`obj = {f1:string, f2:url}` with 

    url ={text:string, href:string}

Answer (score 0):

Ok I believe I know what you want to do .. You basically want to get a nested Value from a Array inside of your object array. Hey all part of the learning process .. So this is a solution.. Your Service Prob looks like this

```
`   getUrlAnchors() { 
        return [
          {href:'h1', text:'t1'},
          {href:'h2', text:'t2'},
          {href:'h3', text: [
            { href: 'h4', text: 'nestedValue'}
            ] }
      ]
    }`
```

And so you do have to iterate over a Array with *ngFor ..

```
    //our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, OnInit} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

import {UrlService} from './url-service'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div><h2>{{title}}</h2></div>
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>
        HREF
        </td>
        <td>
        TEXT
        </td>
      </tr>
      </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let r of anchors">
      <td><span>{{ r.href }}</span></td>
      <td *ngIf="r.text.length > 1"><span>{{ r.text }}</span></td>
      <td *ngIf="r.text.length < 2">
        <span *ngFor="let nested of r.text">
          {{ nested.text }}
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
  `,
})
export class App implements OnInit {
  title:string;
  public anchors;

  constructor(public urlObj: UrlService) {
    this.title = 'URL Example'
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.anchors = this.urlObj.getUrlAnchors();
  }

}
```

Working Plunker here hopes this helps .. [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/JsLO3hQzSjG2O3I9IuBX/)

Comment: Yeah so you have to find out if the value is a nested array or not so I'm checking the length of the object property and then saying if this is x > 1 then show r.text and if it is < 2 show nested.text .. Understand??